# What does => operator means in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm just wondering what  `=>`  means such as the following code using Alamofire:

```
JSONEncoding() => ["curious": true]
```

I tried to find the answer using Apple's Swift documentation but haven't found any useful information

Comment: Command click it.

Comment: Wow haven't thought of command-clicking the operator itself! Thanks @Alexander

Comment: because this is custom operator defined in Alamofire framework, you have to check Alamofire's documentation

Comment: @user3441734 - Are you sure it's defined in Alamofire? I don't see it there. I suspect it's some other library.

Comment: @Rob I don't have an idea where it is defined, you are right

Comment: sorry i failed to mention that the library I'm using is [MoyaSugar](https://github.com/devxoul/MoyaSugar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending a couple hours of looking for an answer, it seems that I haven't read much of Apple's Swift documentation regarding [advanced operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html). Now I can conclude that this  `=>` operator is not a Swift default one. Hence, a custom infix operator defined somewhere along the libraries that I've used.

In my case it is defined as this:

```
infix operator => : DefaultPrecedence

public func =>(encoding: ParameterEncoding, values: [String : Any]) -> Parameters
```

Comment: Correct, this is not a standard operator, but rather a custom operator, but not one defined by Alamofire, itself, either, AFAIK. Out of curiosity, in which library did you find this custom operator defined?

Comment: @Rob sorry i failed to mention that the library I'm using is [MoyaSugar](https://github.com/devxoul/MoyaSugar)